# Add inner element via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `jquery 3` and I would like to add an inner `span`-tag with a styling.

```js
var data = "test1, test2, test3";
var dataArr = data.split(',');
var restArr = dataArr.slice(1);

var $elem = $('<span>', {
  'data-function': "addSynonym",
  'data-options': '[' + restArr.join(',') + ']'
});

$elem[0].innerText = dataArr[0]
console.log($elem[0])

// WANTED Output: <span data-function="addSynonym" data-options="[test2, test3]"><span style="background-color: yellow;">test1</span></span>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The final result should look like the following (notice the additional wanted " " before and after the tag:

`<span data-function="addSynonym" data-options="[test2, test3]"><span style="background-color: yellow;">test1</span></span>`

Any suggestions how to create the inner element?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: I guess you can use `innerHTML` on that `span` what you already edit to add inner element.

Comment: `$elem.append($('<span>', { ... }));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could continue in the same way and use the `html` attribute to pass the inner element

```js
var data = "test1, test2, test3";
var dataArr = data.split(',');
var restArr = dataArr.slice(1);

var $elem = $('<span>', {
  'data-function': "addSynonym",
  'data-options': '[' + restArr.join(',').trim() + ']',
  'html': $('<span>', {
    'text': dataArr[0],
    'css': {
      backgroundColor: 'yellow'
    }
  })
});

// without spaces
console.log($elem[0].outerHTML)
// with spaces
console.log(` ${$elem[0].outerHTML} `);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is it also possible to add the spaces, when creating the node?

Comment: no, when creating the node you start from the node and its inner contents, so you cannot add something outside of it. You could add another wrapper node and use the ` ${$elem[0].outerHTML} ` for its html.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = "test1, test2, test3";
var dataArr = data.split(',');
var restArr = dataArr.slice(1);

var $elem = $('<span>', {
  'data-function': "addSynonym",
  'data-options': '[' + restArr.join(',') + ']'
});

var $innerElem = $('<span>' + dataArr[0] + '</span>').css({
  backgroundColor: "yellow"
})

$elem.append($innerElem);

console.log($elem[0].outerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thx for your reply! How can I add an extra space at the outer Element?

Answer (score 0):

As I have mentioned in the comment section, maybe one solution can be to use `html()` to append the already found `span`. Similarly like using `innerHTML`.

About [`.html(htmlString)`](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) please read from the documentation:

> Set the HTML contents of each element in the set of matched elements.

Working example:

```js
var data = "test1, test2, test3";
var dataArr = data.split(',');
var restArr = dataArr.slice(1);

var $elem = $('<span>', {
  'data-function': "addSynonym",
  'data-options': '[' + restArr.join(',') + ']'
});

$($elem[0]).html(`<span style="background-color: yellow;">${dataArr[0]}</span>`);
console.log($elem[0]);
console.log($elem[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I hope that helps!